# Why N[...] Function is opperationg on the index

Tags: programming

i have following problem. I have an expression with some variables `a[i]`. When i use the `N[]` function in Mathematica i want them to stay as they are because unfortunately `a[1.]` will not be recognized as `a[1]` afterwards.

```
In[155]:= therm = \[Pi] a[1] a[2];

In[156]:= therm // N

Out[156]= 3.14159 a[1.] a[2.]
```

Does anyone has an idea how to solve that?

Many thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: so `SetAttributes[a, NHoldAll]` should do what you need. Let me know if not or you disagree with closing.

Comment: Look up `NHoldFirst` and `NHoldRest` as well.